# Keras: apply masking to non-sequential data

Tags: keras, time-series, lstm, multilabel-classification

I am trying to do multi-label classification via LSTM in Keras.

As a simple example, suppose I have sequences of length 4. Each sequence element is a 3x3 numpy array with values 0, 1, or -1, like this:

```
-1  1 -1
 0 -1  0
 1  0 -1
```

The -1 values indicate that this position of the numpy array should be ignored (no weight calculation, no associated gradient update, no contribution to the cost function, etc). The positions of the -1 values are the same in each 3x3 numpy array. The 0/1 values are the labels for each position.

How can I tell Keras to ignore the values -1 in my input? I have tried one-hot encoding each 0/1/-1 value and using a mask that way (since masking does not accept 1D input). I also saw that masking is applied to dimension 1 of the (num_samples, num_timesteps, num_features) input shape, which is not what I want: I want it applied to the features (the 3x3 numpy arrays).

Does the below code do what I want it to do?

```
from keras.layers import Input, Masking, LSTM, Dense, Flatten
from keras.models import Model
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from keras import backend as K
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras.optimizers import adam

#Creating some sample data

#Matrix has size 3*3, values -1, 0, 1
X = np.random.rand(3, 3).flatten()
X[X < 0.2] = 0.
X[(X >= 0.2) & (X < 0.4)] = 1.
X[X >= 0.4] = -1

X2 = np.random.rand(4, 3*3)
for i in range(X2.shape[0]):
    X2[i,:][(X==-1.)] = -1.
    X2[i,:][(X !=-1.)] = 0.
    tobeone = int(len(np.where(X2[i,:] == 0.)[0])*0.5)
    selected_ones = np.random.choice(np.where(X2[i,:] == 0.)[0], tobeone)
    X2[i,selected_ones] = 1.

X = np.reshape(X, ((1, 3*3)))
X_new = np.concatenate((X, X2), axis=0)
Y = X_new[4,:]
X = X_new[:4,:]

#Categories are 0, 1, -1 one-hot encoded
X = to_categorical(X, num_classes=3)
X = np.reshape(X, (4, 3, 3*3)) #X needs to be shape (num_samples, num_timesteps, num_features), not sure if I have this right

Y = to_categorical(Y, num_classes=3)
y_true = np.reshape(Y, (1, 3, 3*3)) #predicting a single timestep

#Building the model

mask_val = np.tile([0,0,1], 3*3).reshape((3, 3*3))
input_tensor = Input(shape=(3, 3*3))
masking_input = Masking(mask_value=mask_val)(input_tensor)
lstm = LSTM(1, return_sequences=True)(masking_input)
output = Dense(3*3, activation='sigmoid')(lstm)

model = Model(input_tensor, output)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
print(model.summary())

y_pred = model.predict(X)

#See if the model's loss is the same as the unmasked loss (shouldn't be)
print(model.evaluate(np.expand_dims(X[0,:,:], axis=0), y_true))
```

Comment: Just a shot in the dark (I don't know that it is compatible with Keras - never tried it)... you could try using the [masked arrays provided by numpy itself](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/maskedarray.generic.html#what-is-a-masked-array). I"m not sure how Keras would treat these.
Alternatively, you could maintain the masked array parallel to the weight matrices and enforce them where appropriate, so the corresponding weights are not updated during backprop. You will probably have to do this in a more involved way though, leaning more on Tensorflow that Keras.